# Sharing a keyboard over point to point network

Tags: linux, input, socat

I tried following  https://superuser.com/questions/67659/linux-share-keyboard-over-network but had no success with the #1 solution.

Then I tried socat and I had partial success -- it does work but stops working after a little while (Socats on both the client and the server stay alive and no error messages are printed, but the keypresses seem to be no longer transmitted. I wasn't able to figure out what causes it to stop working. For a while, everything seems to get transmitted, including keypresses to switch virtual consoles, etc.)

Any ideas on how to make this work without breaking at some random point and also how to disable the server operating system from processing the keypresses -- I just want them transmitted without having any effect on the server computer.

What I did:

Both client and server:

```
cd /dev/input/by-path
sudo su
```

Client (the one without the keybaord):

```
socat TCP:"$SERVER_IP:$SERVER_PORT" "GOPEN:$PWD/`readlink *kbd`"
```

Server (the one with the keyboard):

```
socat "GOPEN:$PWD/`readlink *kbd`" TCP-LISTEN:"$SERVER_PORT",reuseaddr
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative possibility is to share a (usb) keyboard over the network using
**usbip**. This is a kernel module and daemon that locks on to a usb device of
your chosing and sends its i/o over the netweork to a similar setup on a remote where it is seen as a local usb device.

Here's a [howto](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-a-usb-over-ip-server-and-client-with-ubuntu-10.04)
for ubuntu.

This will stop the system with the keyboard seeing the keypresses.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually trying to get that one to work right now. Unfortunately the one in the repos of my Mintbox seems to be missing the required kernel modules.